# Using Haskell's type system to enforce modularity

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

I'm thinking about ways to use Haskell's type system to enforce modularity in a program.  For example, if I have a web application, I'm curious if there's a way to separate all database code from CGI code from filesystem code from pure code.

For example, I'm envisioning a DB monad, so I could write functions like:

```
countOfUsers :: DB Int
countOfUsers = select "count(*) from users"
```

I would like it to be impossible to use side effects other than those supported by the DB monad.  I am picturing a higher-level monad that would be limited to direct URL handlers and would be able to compose calls to the DB monad and the IO monad.

Is this possible?  Is this wise?

**Update**: I ended up achieving this with Scala instead of Haskell: http://moreindirection.blogspot.com/2011/08/implicit-environment-pattern.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am picturing a higher-level monad that would be limited to direct URL handlers and would be able to compose calls to the DB monad and the IO monad.

You can certainly achieve this, and get very strong static guarantees about the separation of the components.

At its simplest, you want a restricted IO monad. Using something like a "tainting" technique, you can create a set of IO operations lifted into a simple wrapper, then use the module system to hide the underlying constructors for the types.

In this way you'll only be able to run CGI code in a CGI context, and DB code in a DB context. There are many examples on Hackage.

Another way is to construct an interpreter for the actions, and then use data constructors to describe each primitive operation you wish. The operations should still form a monad, and you can use do-notation, but you'll instead be building a data structure  that describes the actions to run, which you then execute in a controlled way via an interpreter.

This gives you perhaps more introspection than you need in typical cases, but the approach does give you full power to insspect user code before you execute it.

Comment: Thanks, Don!  The former solution sounds like what I'm looking for.  Do you know any specific packages that use this technique, or good terms to google for ("restricted IO monad" didn't turn up much)?

Comment: A good example of the 'taint monad' concept, http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/04/trivial-monad.html

Comment: Thanks.  If I choose to use the "tainted monad" pattern for my DB monad, what do I do to extract the data from the DB monad?  Does my HTTP action handler have to use a monad transformer with DB in it?

Comment: Most monads come with a "run" command.  The usual pattern is that monad type Foo has "runFoo :: Foo a -> a".

On the other hand you may want to restrict the destination of your output, so you might have "runFoo :: Foo a -> Bar a"

Comment: Afterthought: Or if runFoo has to do IO then it would be "runFoo :: Foo a -> IO a".  In your case it sounds like you want the only IO that CGI can cause to be databases, so "runDB :: DB a -> CGI a", and then have a top-level "runCGI :: CGI a -> IO a".

Comment: Also have a look at "Monads a la carte". (I *think* that's the title...)

Answer (score 5):

I think there's a third way beyond the two Don Stewart mentioned, which may even be simpler:

```
class Monad m => MonadDB m where
    someDBop1 :: String -> m ()
    someDBop2 :: String -> m [String]

class Monad m => MonadCGI m where
    someCGIop1 :: ...
    someCGIop2 :: ...

functionWithOnlyDBEffects :: MonadDB m => Foo -> Bar -> m ()
functionWithOnlyDBEffects = ...

functionWithDBandCGIEffects :: (MonadDB m, MonadCGI m) => Baz -> Quux -> m ()
functionWithDBandCGIEffects = ...

instance MonadDB IO where
    someDBop1 = ...
    someDBop2 = ...

instance MonadCGI IO where
    someCGIop1 = ...
    someCGIop2 = ...
```

The idea is very simply that you define type classes for the various subsets of operations you want to separate out, and then parametrize your functions using them. Even if the only concrete monad you ever make an instance of the classes is IO, the functions parametrized on any MonadDB will still only be allowed to use MonadDB operations (and ones built from them), so you achieve the desired result. And in a "can do anything" function in the IO monad, you can use MonadDB and MonadCGI operations seamlessly, because IO is an instance.

(Of course, you *can* define other instances if you want to. Ones to lift the operations through various monad transformers would be straightforward, and I think there's actually nothing stopping you from writing instances for the "wrapper" and "interpreter" monads Don Stewart mentions, thereby combining the approaches - although I'm not sure if there's a reason you would want to.)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this question!

I did some work on a client/server web framework that used monads to distinguish between different exection environments. The obvious ones were *client-side* and *server-side*, but it also allowed you to write *both-side* code (which could run on both client and server, because it didn't contain any special features) and also *asynchronous client-side* which was used for writing non-blocking code on the client (essentially a continuation monad on the client-side). This sounds quite related to your idea of distinguishing between CGI code and DB code.

Here are some resources about my project:

- [Slides](http://tomasp.net/fswebtools/files/fswebtoolkit_v1.pdf) from a presentation that I did about the project
- [Draft paper](http://tomasp.net/fswebtools/files/fswebtoolkit-ml.pdf) that I wrote with Don Syme
- And I also wrote my [Bachelor thesis](http://tomasp.net/articles/webtools-thesis/fswebtools.pdf) on this subject (which is quite long though)

I think this is an interesting approach and it can give you interesting guarantees about the code. There are some tricky questions though. If you have a server-side function that takes an `int` and returns `int`, then what should be the type of this function? In my project, I used `int -> int server` (but it may be also possible to use `server (int -> int)`.

If you have a couple of functions like this, then it isn't as straightforward to compose them. Instead of writing `goo (foo (bar 1))`, you need to write the following code:

```
do b <- bar 1
   f <- foo b
   return goo f
```

You could write the same thing using some combinators, but my point is that composition is a bit less elegant.

Comment: `import Control.Monad; (goo <=< foo <=< bar) 1` ... yeah, it is not quite as clean, but still not *too* too bad.

Comment: Yeah, this was worse in F# where you also wanted to write method calls such as `o.Bar().Foo().Goo()` and there is no way to do this using combinators. Using `<=<` in Haskell seems OK, but still not perfect.